Excel automatically adding @ to function added via openpyxl
I'm trying to dynamically add a function of a third-party Excel addon, row by row to my excel file like so:
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import FORMULAE
# Load workbook
wb = load_workbook("Book4.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

for i in range(0, len(df['ticker'])):
    formula = f'=WI.COMPANY_FINANCIAL_STATEMENT("{df["ticker"][i]}")'
    ws[f'A${2*i + 1}'].value = formula

# Save the workbook
wb.save('Book4.xlsx')

But in my Book4.xlsx file, the formula inserted turned out to be
=@WI.COMPANY_FINANCIAL_STATEMENT("AAA")

As you might see, an @ was automatically added, which broke the function entirely. How should I address this problem?
I noticed that this question was previously answered multiple times, but with people using VBA to add functions. I'm trying to manipulate a sheet via Python, and nowhere have I found a satisfying solution. ChatGPT and Youtube doesn't seem to be of great help as well.
I have tried adding _xlfn., as per the solution here and got =@_xlfn.WI.COMPANY_FINANCIAL_STATEMENT("AAA"), and ws.formula_attributes here, and got AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'formula_attributes'.
